# Is it possible to get and use angular form validator's result object?

Tags: angular

According to the documentation, The validator can return an object `{[key: string]: any}` or `null`

So it means it can return an object (for `any`) and the object can contain full info to what is wrong with that validation.

For instance:

```
function validateUserName(c: FormControl) {
    ...
    return {
        'validateUserName': {
            tooShort: true,
            spacesExist: true,
            numbersExist: true
        }
    }
}
```

**Q:** Is it possible some way to get the returned object to use it in the form component class?

Certainly we can use three validators instead of this one, but I'm wondering if there is such a possibility.

Comment: Maybe just try it?

Comment: using `form.errors` will give you all error reported by validators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    control.getError('validateUserName');
```

You can also use `control.errors` but it's not recommended and as far as I know the AOT compiler will throw.

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible using Angulars Custom Validators.

Here's an example from [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators):

```
/** A hero's name can't match the given regular expression */
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
        const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
        return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
    };
}
```

With this said if you add several different `Validators` to a single `Control` the errors will be returned as an array by default, so it would be going against the grain to try come up with a Validator for a specific input.

As per your given code it might be best to have three different validators attached to the one input- `tooShortStringValidator`, `spacesExistValidator` and `numbersExistValidator`, that way they are more reusable.

Usage like so:

```
this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
    'userName': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
        Validators.required,
        tooShortStringValidator(), // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom
        spacesExistValidator(),
        numbersExistValidator()
    ]),
    'justNoNumbersInput': new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo, [
        Validators.required,
        numbersExistValidator()
    ]),
});
```